# If I am employed in the UK but WFH from another country, am I a UK tax resident?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, tax-law

I have a standard full-time engineer contract in the UK with a company that is pretty big and has offices here and there in the world.

Due to personal reasons, I'm working from France, since all I need is a computer. My manager is fine with that, but we haven't really asked HR. And I have spent only 2 weeks in the UK this year.

Am I considered a UK tax resident or a France tax resident?

Edit: Im making somewhere between 50.000 and 100.000 pounds, I'm a french citizen, and I receive my salary on an English bank account.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Is your question about income tax? Are you a French or UK citizen? Do you receive your salary in UK or France? Or, do you get it thorough online transactions like paypal? How much do you earn?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You will get taxed by the UK authorities (under PAYE), *and* be liable for income tax in France.  The good news is that you can offset any tax you pay in the UK against any liability to pay tax in France (under dual taxation treaties).

The French tax authorities are quite used to this - there are lots of French residents working in Switzerland.  (Of course, the authority in your *Department* may not have encountered this before, but they will have procedures for it).

I suspect the UK authorities are much less used to this - but they don't need to be.

Comment: not sure to understand the "be liable for income tax in France"
if I have to pay this year 10 k £ in UK (already deduced from my monthly salary) and 10 k€ in France, then I will tell the french authorities that I am already paying in UK and so I don't have to pay them anything ? or it is the other way around ? (UK will give me back some money ?)

also is what Im doing legal ? people who live in france and work in switzerland actually work there and are at work every day in switzerland. They don't have a contract in switzerland and work from home in france

Comment: friendly ping, in case you didn't get notified

Comment: I didn't.  You've paid £10k in UK.  You would owe the French authorities 10k€, but you can deduct the £10k from that - which is (at the moment at least) less than zero, so you don't owe the French authorities anything.

Comment: I don't see why what you are doing *shouldn't* be legal - free movement of people and all that.